# ffmpeg + libfaac compilation error in Android

Tags: android, gcc, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have successfully integrated and compiled ffmpeg with libfaac. When I am trying to compile libfaac functions I'm getting this error:

```
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../obj/local/armeabi/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o): In function `Faac_encode_close':
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:145: undefined reference to `faacEncClose'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../obj/local/armeabi/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o): In function `Faac_encode_frame':
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:129: undefined reference to `faacEncEncode'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../obj/local/armeabi/libavcodec.a(libfaac.o): In function `Faac_encode_init':
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:47: undefined reference to `faacEncOpen'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:52: undefined reference to `faacEncGetCurrentConfiguration'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:55: undefined reference to `faacEncClose'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:76: undefined reference to `faacEncClose'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:103: undefined reference to `faacEncGetDecoderSpecificInfo'
/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../jni/ffmpeg/libavcodec/libfaac.c:115: undefined reference to `faacEncSetConfiguration'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [/home/admin1/Desktop/android/workspace/.../obj/local/armeabi/libxyz.so] Error 1
```

I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `Android.mk`'s `LOCAL_LDLIBS`...

I forgot to add a reference to my `libfaac.a` file in `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -ldl -lgcc -llog -lz -lm -lc -lstdc++ -L$(LOCAL_PATH) -lfaac
```

Comment: Hi how did u integrated and compiled ffmpeg with libfaac? can u share it with me.